# Select ID from table2 insert into table1

Tags: sql-server, subquery, sql-insert

I have two tables - table Kontrahent and table Orders. First, I insert data into the `Kontrahent` table, then into the `Orders` table. Inserting into Orders, in the IDAccount column I have to insert the value from the IDKontrahent column from the Kontrahent table. How?

```php
    try {
    //Wstawianie nowego kontrahenta 
    $query = "INSERT INTO  dbo.Kontrahent (Nazwa,Odbiorca,Dostawca,NIP,Regon,Uwagi,KodPocztowy,Miejscowosc,UlicaLokal,AdresWWW,Email,Utworzono,Zmodyfikowano,Telefon,Fax,OsobaKontaktowa,Pracownik,IDKraju,NrKonta,SWIFT,NazwaBanku,IDPaymentType,Archiwalny,IDRodzajuTransportu,SupplyCity,UlicaDostawy,KodPocztowyDostawy,NazwaAdresuDostawy,OsobaKontaktowaDostawy,TelefonDostawy,IDPlatnikaVat,CzyFirma,CzyGlownaFirma,NazwaKonta,LimitKredytu,IDPriceList) VALUES ('$complete_billing_name',1,0,'','','','$billing_postcode','$billing_state','$billing_address','','$billing_email','$isoDate','$ModDate',$billing_phone,'',NULL,0,616,'','','',NULL,0,NULL,'','','','','','',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)";

    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
     var_dump($result);
    unset($query);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    die(print_r($e->getMessage()));
  }
```

This not working :

```php
try{
$select = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(Kontrahent) ";
    $result22 = $conn->query($select);
    $result22 ->execute();
$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (IDOrderType, IDAccount, Number, IDOrderStatus, IDPaymentType, Remarks, IDUser, IDWarehouse, IDCurrency, IDCompany) VALUES (15,$result22,$customer_id,2,1,NULL,1,10,1,1)";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    var_dump($result);
    unset($result);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    die(print_r($e->getMessage()));
  }
```

---

## EDIT:

### The current code looks like this:

```php
  // Inserting data into Order:
     // IDOrder (broadcast automatically)
     // Set OrderTypeID = 15 for orders from customers (14 orders from suppliers, 16 are offers)
     // IDAccount - is the customer ID from the Contractor table
     // Number - is the document number, e.g. order number from presta
     // IDOrderStatus - is the current status of the order from the OrderStatus table (e.g. Open or you can add your own ..)
     // IDPaymentType - this is the payment method for the order (from the PaymentTypes table)
     // Remarks - Order notes
     // IDUser - what user creates this entry, e.g. 1 = Admin (Users table)
     // IDWarehouse - in which warehouse to create the order (ID from the Warehouse table)
     // IDCurrency = 1 for PLN
    // IDCompany = 1
   // Get ID       
   $query = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Kontrahent') AS ID";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
       die("Error executing query.");
   };
   $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $id = $result;
   var_dump($result);
   print_r($id);
   $stmt = null;

   // Insert into Orders
   $query = "
       INSERT INTO dbo.Orders 
           (IDOrderType, 
            IDAccount, 
            Number, 
            IDOrderStatus, 
            IDPaymentType, 
            Remarks, 
            IDUser, 
            IDWarehouse, 
            IDCurrency, 
            IDCompany) 
       VALUES 
           (15, ?, ?, 2, 1, NULL, 1, 10, 1, 1)
   ";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->bindValue(2, $customer_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
   if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
       die("Error executing query.");
   };
print_r($stmt);
   $stmt = null;
```

```php
   // Get ID Order from Orders
   $query = "SELECT TOP 1 IDOrder FROM dbo.Orders ORDER BY IDOrder DESC";
   //$query ="SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Orders') AS IDTowaru";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        die("Error executing query.");
    };
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $idorder = $result;
    var_dump ($idorder, $result);
    $stmt = null;
```

Search for IDTowaru by KodKreskowy. the KodKreskowy is only one identical in the store and application.

```php
    $query = "SELECT IDTowaru FROM dbo.Towar WHERE KodKreskowy = '$product_sku' ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        die("Error executing query.");
    };
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $iditem = $result;
    var_dump($iditem);
    $stmt = null;
```

Inserting OrderLines with IDItem from Towar table and IDOrder from Orders table

```php
 // Inserting into OrderLines:
     // IDOrderLine (broadcast automatically)
     // IDOrder - Id of the order header from the Order table
     // IDItem -ID of the item from the Item or Current Status table
     // Quantity - Quantity of the item
     // PriceNet - net price
     // PriceGross - gross price including VAT
     // IDVat - VAT rate ID from the VATRates table
     // Remarks - any additional comments
     // IDUser - what user creates this entry, e.g. 1 = Admin (Users table)
    $query = "
       INSERT INTO dbo.OrderLines
           (IDItem, 
           IDOrder,
           Quantity, 
           PriceNet, 
           PriceGross, 
           IDVat, 
           Remarks, 
           IDUser) 
       VALUES 
           (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1, 1, 1)
   ";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bindParam(1, $iditem, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->bindParam(2, $idorder, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->bindValue(3, $quantity, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
   $stmt->bindValue(4, $product_price, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
   $stmt->bindValue(5, $product_price, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
   if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
       die("Error executing query.");
   };
   $stmt = null;


  } catch (Exception $e) {
    die(print_r($e->getMessage()));
  }
}
```

This is error :

```sql
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_OrderLines_Towar". The conflict occurred in database "greenmonkey", table "dbo.Towar", column 'IDTowaru'. [20018] (severity 16) [ INSERT INTO dbo.OrderLines (IDItem, IDOrder,Quantity, PriceNet, PriceGross, IDVat, Remarks, IDUser) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1) ]1
```

Why IDAccount and Number is 1?

```sql
object(PDOStatement)#14917 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(225) " INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (IDOrderType, IDAccount, Number, IDOrderStatus, IDPaymentType, Remarks, IDUser, IDWarehouse, IDCurrency, IDCompany) VALUES (15, ?, ?, 2, 1, NULL, 1, 10, 1, 1) " } array(1) { ["IDTowaru"]=> float(99) } array(1) { ["IDTowaru"]=> int(825) }
```

Next, why IDOrder and IDItem is 1?

```sql
[ INSERT INTO dbo.OrderLines (IDItem, IDOrder,Quantity, PriceNet, PriceGross, IDVat, Remarks, IDUser) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1) ]1
```

Comment: You really need to fix that injection issue first. Read about, learn how to use and then implement prepared/parametrised statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should consider at least the following:

- you need to prepare and execute your statements using [PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [PDOStatement::execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)
- you need to use parameterized statements to prevent SQL injection issues and set each parameter value using [PDOStatement::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)
- you need to fetch the result from your `SELECT` statement using [PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

The next example, based on your code, may help to find a solution to your problem:

```
<?php
try{
    // Insert into Kontrahent
    $query = "
        INSERT INTO dbo.Kontrahent 
            (Nazwa, Odbiorca, Dostawca, NIP, Regon, Uwagi, KodPocztowy, Miejscowosc, UlicaLokal, AdresWWW, Email, Utworzono, Zmodyfikowano, Telefon, Fax, OsobaKontaktowa, Pracownik, IDKraju, NrKonta, SWIFT, NazwaBanku, IDPaymentType, Archiwalny, IDRodzajuTransportu, SupplyCity, UlicaDostawy, KodPocztowyDostawy, NazwaAdresuDostawy, OsobaKontaktowaDostawy,TelefonDostawy,  IDPlatnikaVat, CzyFirma, CzyGlownaFirma, NazwaKonta, LimitKredytu, IDPriceList) 
        VALUES 
            (?, 1, 0, '', '', '', ?, ?, ?, '', ?, ?, ?, ?, '', NULL, 0, 616, '', '', '', NULL, 0, NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
        ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $complete_billing_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $billing_postcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $billing_state, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $billing_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $billing_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $isoDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(7, $ModDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(8, $billing_phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        die("Error executing query.");
    };
    $stmt = null;

    // Get ID       
    $query = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Kontrahent') AS ID";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        die("Error executing query.");
    };
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $stmt = null;

    // Insert into Orders
    $query = "
        INSERT INTO dbo.Orders 
            (IDOrderType, IDAccount, Number, IDOrderStatus, IDPaymentType, Remarks, IDUser, IDWarehouse, IDCurrency, IDCompany) 
        VALUES 
            (15, ?, ?, 2, 1, NULL, 1, 10, 1, 1)
    ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $customer_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        die("Error executing query.");
    };
    $stmt = null;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    die(print_r($e->getMessage()));
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Zhorov ! But this is error : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 The multi-part identifier "dbo.Kontrahent" could not be bound. [20018] (severity 16) [SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(dbo.Kontrahent) AS ID]1

Comment: @BartoszXxX The answer is updated - it's `IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Kontrahent')`, not `IDENT_CURRENT(dbo.Kontrahent)`.

Comment: I update my code with your suggestions. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What do you think? Thanks for reply